# Why do I need `display: flex` in the code to the technique for aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css

I wrote the following code, referring to the [link](https://arts-factory.net/ratio/).
(The reference article is in Japanese, I just want to make it clear that I used it as a reference, so it doesn't matter if you can't read the reference article)

I wrote the code to make a square as shown below, but I don't know why `display: flex` is necessary for this technique.

What is the specification of `display: flex` that makes it work?

CSS Code:

```
.squareBasedOnWidth {
    display: flex;
}
.squareBasedOnWidth:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div style="width: 100px; background-color: green;">
    <div class="squareBasedOnWidth"></div>
</div>
```

---

I read your response and wondered about it, so I gave it a try.
The code in your comment is indeed working, but when I tried it from scratch, it didn't work.

With `flex`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    .squareBasedOnWidth {
        display: flex;
    }
    .squareBasedOnWidth:before{
        content: "";
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 100px; background-color: green;">
        <div class="squareBasedOnWidth"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Without `flex`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    .squareBasedOnWidth:before{
        content: "";
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 100px; background-color: green;">
        <div class="squareBasedOnWidth"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Oh, I understand.

I just delete `flex` and add `block` to `squareBasedOnWidth:befor`, right?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    .squareBasedOnWidth:before{
        display: block;
        content: "";
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 100px; background-color: green;">
        <div class="squareBasedOnWidth"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

However, the movement seems to change when elements are placed inside.

### With `flex`, and inside element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    .squareBasedOnWidth {
        display: flex;
    }
    .squareBasedOnWidth:before{
        content: "";
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 100px; background-color: green;">
        <div class="squareBasedOnWidth">
            Foo <!-- inside element -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

### Without `flex` and add `block`, and inside element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    .squareBasedOnWidth:before{
        display: block;
        content: "";
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 100px; background-color: green;">
        <div class="squareBasedOnWidth">
            Foo <!-- inside element -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

If I specify `block` instead of `flex`,
I will not get the height.
The element specifying the padding just sticks out.

Why is that?
Why does `flex` get the height?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    .squareBasedOnWidth {
        display: block;  /* replace to block */
    }
    .squareBasedOnWidth:before{
        content: "";
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 100px; background-color: green;">
        <div class="squareBasedOnWidth">
            Foo <!-- inside element -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's not: https://jsfiddle.net/b1dnfejo/

Comment: and your code can be simplified: https://jsfiddle.net/b1dnfejo/1/

Comment: display: flex is not necessary to make it work. padding-bottom: 100% is based on the parent element's width. Therefore you just need to make sure you can assign a width to you're parent element (e.g. display: block, display: flex...)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I wondered about this, so I tried a few things and added to the question.

Comment: inline element do not accept vertical padding, turn it at least into inline-block or a float element to produce a BFC block formatting context https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

Comment: I had set the pseudo-element to `display: block;`,
but I forget to give it in some places(some snippets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the movement seems to change when elements are placed inside.

Using

```
display: flex;
```

```css
.squareBasedOnWidth {
   display: flex;
}
.squareBasedOnWidth:before {
   background-color: yellow;
   content: "1";
   width: 10px;
   height: 0;
   padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100px; background-color: green;">
   <div class="squareBasedOnWidth">
      2
   </div>
</div>
```

your pseudo-element becomes a flex-item. Flex-items by default are aligned from left to right. Content inside "squareBasedOnWidth" renders as the second column right after you're pseudo-element. Because you're pseudo-element's width is set to 0, everything inside the "sqaureBasedOnWidth" div renders in the top-left corner.

Setting it to

```
display: block
```

everything inside "sqaureBasedOnWidth" renders below your pseudo-element that has a height of 100%. You don't keep the aspect ratio anymore because you're box is now 100% + the height of the content inside "sqaureBasedOnWidth".

```css
.squareBasedOnWidth:before {
   background-color: yellow;
   display: block;
   content: "";
   width: 100%;
   height: 0;
   padding-bottom: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div style="width: 100px; background-color: green;">
   <div class="squareBasedOnWidth">
      block element
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why does the height look good for `flex`?  I added a question.

Comment: That's because pseudo-elements are 'display: inline' by default. You can't specify a height on an inline element. You'd have to set it to 'block' or 'flex' for example. Setting you're parent element to flex makes the pseudo-element a flex-item that adapts the height of it's parent element.

Comment: Did the default change because I set it to `flex`? Or is it originally `display: inline`?

Comment: Yes, as already mentioned. Default of your pseudo-element is inline. Setting the parent to flex makes it a flex-item.

Answer (score 1):

Nowdays, `aspect-ratio` becomes widely avalaible. for latest Edge,Chrome,Firefox and Safari browsers. https://caniuse.com/?search=aspect-ratio

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio
>
> The `aspect-ratio`  CSS property sets a preferred aspect ratio for the box, which will be used in the calculation of auto sizes and some other layout functions.

Give it a try *and drop the pseudo trick* :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .squareBasedOnWidth {
      width: 100px;
      background-color: green;
      aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    }
    .squareBasedOnHeight {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: tomato;
      aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="squareBasedOnWidth">
    calculated from width
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="squareBasedOnHeight">
    calculated from height 
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh. I didn't know about this.